# macOS Mojave 10.4.6 hashes

Tags: macos, mojave, security, install

When I download macOS Mojave via

```
softwareupdate --fetch-full-installer --full-installer-version 10.14.6
```

I get build 18G101, whose hashes are not listed [here](https://github.com/notpeter/apple-installer-checksums). So, what are the dmg hashes for this build number?

EDIT: looks like the Mac App Store download the same build.

Comment: @klanomath I did but no results show up

Comment: Apple recently re-signed a significant portion of their software library and updates.  It may take time for that site to be updated.

Comment: @Hefewe1zen I was hoping that some kind soul with a fast connection could download the installer and post the hashes here. It may be useful too for people that want to take advantage of softwareupdate’s new feature in Catalina.

Comment: Actually do you have an older build?  From here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210589 - 18G103 has supplemental updates.

Comment: @Hefewe1zen I’m trying to downgrade from Catalina to Mojave, so I downloaded the installer using the above command. However, it downloaded build 18G101 (as seen inside Info.plist). I know 18G103 is the latest though.

Comment: Well it seems that the tool is not very reliable according to some comments [here](https://mjtsai.com/blog/2019/10/15/catalina-software-update-can-download-old-installers/)

Comment: @klanomath What os are you downloading it from? Does it download via System Preferences?

Comment: @klanomath Same link, on catalina it downloads the same older build. Probably it uses the same machinery as softwareupdate’s command.

Comment: @Matteo In fact you want to d/l 10.14.6 (18G103). Then use [this](https://github.com/munki/macadmin-scripts/blob/master/installinstallmacos.py) python script: Download it, `cd` to the dir and execute it like this: `sudo ./installinstallmacos.py --catalogurl https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.15-10.14-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog`. If you need help instead simply enter `./installinstallmacos.py -h`. Check this one first: https://github.com/munki/macadmin-scripts/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @klanomath Wow that’s an excellent script. It created an handy sparseimage file (do i just need to burn it to a usb via disk utility)? Also, can please you check your .app/Contents/Info.plist? It still mentions 18G101 and the file date is September 19, even though InstalESD.dmg’s hash is indeed from 18G103.

Comment: @Matteo The DTSDKBuild (here also 18G101) is always (or at least often) smaller than the build number of the finally installed system. You can copy the installer inside the sparseimage to a thumb drive (with a full system) or restore the image to a thumb drive with Disk Utility.